# same content is shown multiple time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to develop filter system using reactjs and rest api. There are two filtering option one is no of room and another is type of property. I have used onChange event whenever user selects say property type home then only spaces with property home type will be listed and if user again selects number of room as 4 then the user will get the space with property type home of 4 rooms.The problem is i am getting same space multiple times. There are only two spaces listingEditNow and Tushant Khatiwada but they are displayed for more 2 times.

What might be the problem?

Here's my code with json file(/api/rentals/)

```
class FilterSpace1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      space:[],
      filter:false,
      propertyType: '',
      rooms: ''
    }
    this.handleFormInput = this.handleFormInput.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
        this.loadRoomFromServer();
    }

    loadRoomFromServer(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/api/rentals/',
            dataType:'json',
            success: (data) => {
                this.setState({space: data.results});
              },
              error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
              }
            });
    }

  handleFormInput(propertyType, rooms) {
    this.setState({
      propertyType: propertyType,
      rooms: rooms,
      filter: !this.state.filter
    })
  }

  render() {
   let space = _.map(this.state.space, (space,id) => {
    return(
            <SpaceFilterResults
            key = {space.id}
            space={this.state.space}
            filter={this.state.filter}
            propertyType={this.state.propertyType}
            rooms={this.state.rooms}
          />
      );

   });
    return (
      <div className="filter">
        <SpaceFilterMenu
          propertyType={this.state.propertyType}
          rooms={this.state.rooms}
          onFormInput={this.handleFormInput}
        />
        {space}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

 class SpaceFilterMenu extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange() {
    console.log('ref',this.refs.propertyTypeInput.value);
    console.log('ref',this.refs.roomsInput.value);
     this.props.onFormInput (
       this.refs.propertyTypeInput.value,
       this.refs.roomsInput.value
     );
   }

   render() {
     return (
      <div className="container filterMenu">
        <div className="row">
           <form className="filter-menu">
             <label htmlFor="roomsInput">Number of rooms</label>
              <select id="roomsInput" ref="roomsInput" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>
                 <option value="5">5</option>
                 <option value="6">6</option>
                 <option value="7">7</option>
                 <option value="8">8</option>
              </select>

             <label htmlFor="propertyTypeInput">propertyType</label>
             <select id="propertyTypeInput" ref="propertyTypeInput" onChange={this.handleChange}>
               <option value="appartment">Appartment</option>
               <option value="house">House</option>
               <option value="shop">Shop</option>
               <option value="bunglow">Bunglow</option>
             </select>
           </form>
          </div>
      </div>
     );
   }
 }

class SpaceFilterResults extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    let results = [];
   if(this.props.filter === false){ 
      this.props.space.map((space) => { 
        results.push(<Space space={space} />) 
      }); 
      } 
      else { 
       this.props.space.map((space) => { 
        console.log('space.property',space.property);
        if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms || space.property === this.props.propertyType){ 
          results.push(<Space space={space} />) 
      } 

  });
}

    return (

             <div className="filter-results">
                <ul className="blocks blocks_3up">
                  {results}
                </ul>
              </div>
    )
  }
}

class Space extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <li className="col-md-4 filterResults">
              <div className="feature-hd">
                <h2 className="hdg hdg_2">{this.props.space.listingName}</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="feature-bd">
                <p>{this.props.space.room}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="feature-ft">
                <p>{this.props.space.property}</p>
              </div>
      </li>
    )
  }
}   

export default FilterSpace1;
```

[image]

There are only 2 spaces(listingListEditedNow and Tushant Khatiwada) but those 2 spaces are shown twice.

[image]

Comment: this.props.space.map((space) => {
    if(this.props.rooms === 0){
      results.push(<Space space={space} />)
    }
    else if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms){
      results.push(<Space space={space} />)
    }
   });
look at your logic. it makes no sense. you are saying just push the same component without any changes based on a prop that is sent

Comment: So what should be done in that logic?

Comment: not sure what exactly you are doing here.. probably something like `if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms)` meaning we have a space that is the correct number of rooms per the selection.. so then push it onto results

Comment: what i want is when user selects 2 then the space with number of room 2 should be displayed and again if user selects from house option from property type then the space with 2 rooms of house should be displayed.

Comment: so if im following, user selects 2. this.props.rooms is 2. when you map over the spaces `if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms){results.push(...)}` is what you want to do. if the space is a house and this.props.propertyType is a house then do the same thing. so putting it together `if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms || space.propertyType === this.props.propertyType){results.push(...)}`

Comment: this.props.space.map((space) => {
    if(this.props.rooms === 0 || this.props.propertyType ===0 ){
      results.push(<Space space={space} />)
    }
    else if (space.rooms === this.props.rooms || space.property === this.props.propertyType){
      results.push(<Space space={space} />)
    }
   });
i did this but still displays nothing when any option is selected.

Comment: do you know how to debug? check the values that are in your props. also what is with the 0? if I select 2 I dont want to see ones with 0 so you should remove that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111277/discussion-between-milan-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111282/discussion-between-milan-and-john-ruddell).

Comment: What is the purpose of `filter: !this.state.filter` in `handleFormInput`? This would toggle `this.state.filter` every time you type something in the field. Doesn’t seem like something you’d want to do.

Comment: I used filter:false at first so that default spaces would be listed at first but when filter option is selected filter will be set true and the spaces will be updated with the value selected by the user.

Comment: just to show list of spaces at first instead of page with only filter option.

Comment: So what should be done, then?

Comment: Somebody please help me